# How to populate datagridview combobox based on the value of other combobox using c#.net windows application

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

I have a datagirdview with two combo-box columns. For example, country and city. If I selected country combo-box in datagridview, the city combo-box column have to bind, based on the selected county using c# .net windows application.

I can't get the selected country value. I have to bind the city combo-box column.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
             if(e.ColumnIndex==0)// Country
            {
                // Build the combox items for CITY

            }                           
    }
```

I assumed ColumnIndex=0 as a Country. After We select country, CellEndEdit event triggered. Inside that event, we can bind City items based on Country as We selected.. Hope this help is Useful...